# How to retrieve from javascript the id of itemplate textbox control aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to retrieve an id of a asp:textbox into an itemplate.
i tried something like this:

```
var pu= window.document.getElementById("prixID");
```

It returns null. I also tried

```
window.document.getElementById("<%=prixID.ClientID%>");
```

It returns that `prixID` isn't in the actual context.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your prixID in the Master page and the script in the web form?

Comment: You have `TextBox` in `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: yes my Textbox is in itemtemplate

Comment: did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

if the textbox control is in hte same page of the script maybe you are missing the

`runat="server"` in the control

if it doesn't work try in this way

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="idTExtBox" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>                      
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then

```
var pu= '<%= ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("idTExtBox").ClientID %>';
```

**update**

try in this way to pass to the script function the id directly in C# code behind code

```
idtext.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:changeprix('" & idtext.ClientId & "')");
idtext.Attributes.Add("class", "disableThis");
```

then in javascript function

```
function changeprix(idOfElement){
   var textBoxes= document.getElementsByClassName("disableThis");
   foreach(var textBox in textBoxes){
        textBox.disabled=true;
   }
   var pu= document.getElementById(idOfElement);

}
```

Comment: thanks. Could i use this code in client side not code behind.

Comment: yes, `var pu= '<%= ((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("idTExtBox").ClientID %>';` is client side

Comment: in code behind i used this:  TextBox idtext = (TextBox)row.FindControl("prixID"); with :GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)child.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

Comment: in code behind i used this:  TextBox idtext = (TextBox)row.FindControl("prixID"); with :GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)child.Rows[e.NewEditIndex]; this work. but i added onchange attribut to idtext like this:idtext.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:changeprix()"); and i tried from client (aspx code) to use window.document.getElementById , to retrieve all others textbox and manipulate them into onchange method

Comment: no it isn't OK. i had this error: "Container" is not exist in actual context."

Comment: i saw your update. but in this situation how can i use other textbox.because my focus is that, onchange i need to disable all textboxs from gridview and maintain just one textbox.

Comment: you can add a specific class to all textbox. Get all textBox with that class and disable them. After this you get your textbox and do what you want

Comment: @DC74 I've updated my answer another time, let me know

Answer (score 0):

the textbox will have id that is combine from all the controls in the hirarchly.
contentplaceholder - if has a master page
gridview
textbox

and a counter of the row/item in grid/repeater

what you want to do with that id?

Comment: i don't use master page. it's a simple web form with separated code behind in c#

Comment: so your id will be gridviewID + textboxID + counter, just look at your source code. but the real thing is why you need it?

Comment: so your id will be gridviewID + textboxID + counter, just look at your source code. but the real thing is why you need it?

Comment: "counter??"  how can i evaluate ou check this counter??